# How should I ask this API question?

Tags: discussion, support

I understand that WordPress added an API to [Gutenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress#WordPress_5.0_%22Bebo%22) that allows themes and plugin developers to create block styles using just PHP calls. I do not know anything about this API and have yet to find any documentation. How can I ask a total beginners question that will get me started?

Would it, for example, be okay to ask for general guidance and/or a pointer to the documentation? Perhaps how I go about initiating a call to the API?